# Define Workflow Lookup

Tags: wss-3.0, workflow

I'm updating a list that requires Lookup Details on 2 fields, but I can't for the life of me see how to do that.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but I think the following answers your question providing you are talking about a SharePoint designer workflow and not a Visual Studio one.

1. create a workflow variable for each lookup
2. Add the 'Set Workflow Variable' workflow action for each lookup.
3. For each action set the name of the variable and click the Workflow Lookup button (fx) to carry out the lookup.

For full details and an example see [this post](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/define-a-workflow-lookup-HA010237830.aspx).

Comment: Thank-you very much for the response, Muhimbi.

What I am trying to do is this...

I have a list as follows:
Name  |  Leave Type  |  Leave Taken  |  Balance

There are 7 Leave Type's for each person.  I need a workflow (using SharePoint Designer) that will update the appropriate "Leave Taken".

For example, if employee John Doe takes 2 days of Vacation Leave, I need to update the Leave Taken field next to the Vacation "Leave Type" for John Doe.

So my workflow needs to lookup the "Name" and "Leave Type" fields and then update the "Leave Taken" field.

I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: That is clear, my assumptions were correct and all the information you need is in my answer and the linked article. Have fun.

Comment: Great!  Thank-you so much for your response and for all of your help.
Have fun?  I most certainly will!

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The OP requires lookup on TWO fields.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no straightforward way to do a lookup based on two fields.

Here are two workarounds:

- create an additional column that concatenates the two fields (using a calculated column or a workflow). You can then lookup this concatenated field.
- create a looping workflow that will go through all the items that match the first field, and then performs a lookup on the second field. This is an advanced customization and actually requires two interlaced workflows.